# Javascript - why the division operator is not working using simple code? (evt.keyCode==111)

Tags: javascript, html, calculator, divide

I'm new on JavaScript & I have a calculator in html and JavaScript and everything working fine 100% just the division **÷** that is not working. When you divided 2 numbers it's showing both of them in one line only

As an example :

50 ÷ 9 = 509

50 ÷ 2 = 502

---

*update
**Full source code** : http://tdiway.blogspot.com/2014/06/calculatrice-en-javascriptpreparer-au.html

**The code:**

```js
calc_array = new Array();
var calcul=0;
var pas_ch=0;
function $id(id)
{
        return document.getElementById(id);
}
function f_calc(id,n)
{
        if(n=='ce')
        {
                initialiser_calc(id);
        }
        else if(n=='=')
        {
                if(calc_array[id][0]!='=' && calc_array[id][1]!=1)
                {
                        eval('calcul='+calc_array[id][2]+calc_array[id][0]+calc_array[id][3]+';');
                        calc_array[id][0] = '=';
                        $id(id+'_resultat').value=calcul;
                        calc_array[id][2]=calcul;
                        calc_array[id][3]=0;
                }
        }
        else if(n=='+-')
        {
                $id(id+'_resultat').value=$id(id+'_resultat').value*(-1);
                if(calc_array[id][0]=='=')
                {
                        calc_array[id][2] = $id(id+'_resultat').value;
                        calc_array[id][3] = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                        calc_array[id][3] = $id(id+'_resultat').value;
                }
                pas_ch = 1;
        }
        else if(n=='nbs')
        {
                if($id(id+'_resultat').value<10 && $id(id+'_resultat').value>-10)
                {
                        $id(id+'_resultat').value=0;
                }
                else
                {
                        $id(id+'_resultat').value=$id(id+'_resultat').value.slice(0,$id(id+'_resultat').value.length-1);
                }
                if(calc_array[id][0]=='=')
                {
                        calc_array[id][2] = $id(id+'_resultat').value;
                        calc_array[id][3] = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                        calc_array[id][3] = $id(id+'_resultat').value;
                }
        }
        else
        {
                        if(calc_array[id][0]!='=' && calc_array[id][1]!=1)
                        {
                                eval('calcul='+calc_array[id][2]+calc_array[id][0]+calc_array[id][3]+';');
                                $id(id+'_resultat').value=calcul;
                                calc_array[id][2]=calcul;
                                calc_array[id][3]=0;
                        }
                        calc_array[id][0] = n;
        }
        if(pas_ch==0)
        {
                calc_array[id][1] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
                pas_ch=0;
        }
        document.getElementById(id+'_resultat').focus();
        return true;
}
function add_calc(id,n)
{
        if(calc_array[id][1]==1)
        {
                $id(id+'_resultat').value=n;
        }
        else
        {
                $id(id+'_resultat').value+=n;
        }
        if(calc_array[id][0]=='=')
        {
                calc_array[id][2] = $id(id+'_resultat').value;
                calc_array[id][3] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
                calc_array[id][3] = $id(id+'_resultat').value;
        }
        calc_array[id][1] = 0;
        document.getElementById(id+'_resultat').focus();
        return true;
}
function initialiser_calc(id)
{
        $id(id+'_resultat').value=0;
        calc_array[id] = new Array('=',1,'0','0',0);
        document.getElementById(id+'_resultat').focus();
        return true;
}
function key_detect_calc(id,evt)
{
        if((evt.keyCode>95) && (evt.keyCode<106))
        {
                var nbr = evt.keyCode-96;
                add_calc(id,nbr);
        }
        else if((evt.keyCode>47) && (evt.keyCode<58))
        {
                var nbr = evt.keyCode-48;
                add_calc(id,nbr);
        }
        else if(evt.keyCode==107)
        {
                f_calc(id,'+');
        }
        else if(evt.keyCode==109)
        {
                f_calc(id,'-');
        }
        else if(evt.keyCode==106)
        {
                f_calc(id,'*');
        }
        else if(evt.keyCode==111)
        {
                f_calc(id,'');
        }
        else if(evt.keyCode==110)
        {
                add_calc(id,'.');
        }
        else if(evt.keyCode==190)
        {
                add_calc(id,'.');
        }
        else if(evt.keyCode==188)
        {
                add_calc(id,'.');
        }
        else if(evt.keyCode==13)
        {
                f_calc(id,'=');
        }
        else if(evt.keyCode==46)
        {
                f_calc(id,'ce');
        }
        else if(evt.keyCode==8)
        {
                f_calc(id,'nbs');
        }
        else if(evt.keyCode==27)
        {
                f_calc(id,'ce');
        }
        return true;
}
```

Please help?
I also tried to add `/` in

```
else if(evt.keyCode==111)
{
        f_calc(id,'/');
}
```

Comment: Because "the simple code" is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode).

Comment: @teemu other working only this, what can i do to fix only the divid?

Comment: You should fix all the code using `keyCode`, reading the linked MDN article: "_Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time._" That "_any time_" might be tomorrow, or even tonight, coming along with a new browser update.

Comment: @teemu what i have to do :( can u help me with something can i use in my project ?

Comment: it might be better if you include your html

Comment: You could look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code which you can map to actual values.

Comment: @beginner the soruce code is here : http://tdiway.blogspot.com/2014/06/calculatrice-en-javascriptpreparer-au.html if you can help :(

Comment: @ShyamBabu i cheacked but i didn't know what i have to do :(

Comment: wherever you are using evt.keyCode replace with evt.code for example evt.keyCode==109 you can replace it with evt.code == 'Minus' and so on. Use this  site https://keycode.info/ to see what maps to what .

Comment: @shyamBabu i swear of the god you an angel ^^ it's donnnnnne ! <3 thank you sooooooooo much

Comment: @Romer Glad to help. all the best :)